# How to find values that can't be cast as date in Redshift?

Tags: sql, date, casting, try-catch, amazon-redshift

I have a big set of data. I try to parse one column to extract a substring that's a date and cast it as such - `date(<substring here>)`. I'm getting an error `ERROR: Error converting text to date` but I don't know what the actual issue is. How do I find the values that are causing a problem? Something like try_cast, but that doesn't work in Redshift. I'm not sure I can use regex since I don't know the format of what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is broad and not very specific as the task which you're trying to solve, so it's hard to provide a correct answer

1. You can use a [pattern matching](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/pattern-matching-conditions-similar-to.html)

Say, you have the following data in `TableA`

| id | dt |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-08-20 |
| 2 | 2021-08-20 |
| 3 | 2021-08-21 |
| 4 | 2021-08-2000 |
| 5 | asdfghjkl |
| 6 | 08-01-2021 |
| 7 | 06/07/2021 |

with pattern matching you can find all the rows with correct dates

```sql
select id from TableA 
where dt similar to '\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}'
  or dt similar to '\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}'
  or dt similar to '\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}'
```

All you need to do now is to reverse this query to find opposites

```sql
select id, dt from TableA
where id not in (
select id from logs.sot 
where dt similar to '\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}'
  or dt similar to '\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}'
  or dt similar to '\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}'
)
```

This will give you result

| id | dt |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | asdfghjkl |
| 4 | 2021-08-2000 |

2. If this does not work, you can try to sort by date column and validate a head and tail - bad values usually live here
3. Use processing outside Redshift if possible. Usually it's good practice to take care about data cleaning before putting it into database. I believe a simple python (or any other language) script will make the job